# Bash: For Loop of Job Arrays - Hoffman2

Tags: python, arrays, bash, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am pretty new to bash code, and I have some basic questions.

I have one job array `job_array_1.sh`, which I am running in Hoffman2.

`job_array_1.sh` is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -o  test.joblog.$JOB_ID.$TASK_ID
#$ -j y
#$ -l h_data=5G,h_rt=00:20:00
#$ -m n
#$ -t 1-5:1

. /u/local/Modules/default/init/modules.sh
module load anaconda3  
#module load python/3.9.6

python3 file1.py $SGE_TASK_ID
```

If, from the terminal I type `qsub job_array_1.sh`, this produces 5 different files with names `test.joblog.$JOB_ID.$TASK_ID` (with the value of `t` as `$TASK_ID`). Notice that in this way the 5 jobs start in a parallel way.

I need to create another file call it `loop.sh` such that it submits the file `job_array_1.sh` sequentially (in this case twice). So far I have:

```
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -l h_data=3G,h_rt=01:00:00
#$ -m n
for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    # job submission scripts or shell scripts
    fname_in1="job_array_1.sh"
    ./$fname_in1 &
    wait    
done
```

When, from the terminal, I type `qsub loop.sh` this does not produce the 5 files that I have if I do `qsub  job_array_1.sh`. How can I modify the `loop.sh` file so that the `job_array_1.sh` produces the 5 files?

Comment: What is an "array job"? I've never heard of that.

Comment: sorry, I was naive. I meant Job Array, I just modified my question. 
"Job array is a type of batch mode. It makes it possible to process different subjects using the same script on multiple Hoffman2 working nodes at the same time." Here the definition: https://www.ccn.ucla.edu/wiki/index.php/Hoffman2:Job_Array

Comment: Hoffman2 seems to be something very specific to UCLA.

Comment: I see, do you know how do people usually do for loops over Job Arrays (even outside Hoffman2)? I could not find a good tutorial or similar :-(

Comment: Your `for` loop is the normal way to do them. You can also use `for i in {1..2}; do`

Comment: Note that your code is using `bash` extensions. Maybe the problem is that Hoffman runs the script with `sh`, not `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing wildly here because I don't know anything about your job submission system, but I do know a little about `bash` and am trying to help. I suspect you need something more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -l h_data=3G,h_rt=01:00:00
#$ -m n
for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
   # job submission scripts or shell scripts
   echo "Loop: $i"
   qsub job_array_1.sh &
done
wait
```

Comment: Hey @mark! thanks for the suggestion. However, ```qsub``` is not recognized as a command within a .sh file.

Comment: Ok, run `type qsub` somewhere it is recognised and you will find its full path. Then inside `loop.sh` use that full path.

Comment: hey Mark! I forgot to thank you!! :-) Super helpful!